# Ruby use conditional operator to check current path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a navbar that highlights the `li` item on which page I am.

In my code below I'm trying to use a conditional operator to see if the current path is correct. Or at least that's what I think i'm doing.

```
<li id="home-link" data-hook class="<%= root_path ? "active" : "" %>"><%= link_to Spree.t(:Home), spree.root_path %></li>
<% if spree_current_user %>
  <li id="home-link" data-hook class="<%= products_path ? "active" : "" %>" ><%= link_to Spree.t(:products), spree.products_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

What I then expect to happen is that if i'm on the home page the `li` get's the class `active`,

what currently happens is that all `li` items get the class active.

How can I check the current path?

Comment: I guess root_path and products_path both return a value which is interpreted as a 'true'. I guess you can check the current controller instead: `if params[:controller] == 'product' ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are testing if the path helpers are `true`, and they are as they return a `String`. That's why `active` is always set.

Take a look at [current_page?](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F):

```rb
<% product_active = 'active' if current_page?(controller: 'products', action: 'index') %>
<li id="home-link" data-hook class="<%= product_active %>">
```

EDIT: As @NensiMakawana suggets, you can alternatively use the [active_link_to](https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to) gem.

Comment: @NensiMakawana, thanks for your suggestion. Next time use a comment for that, please.